# Convert Eigen::ArrayXXd to Eigen::MatrixXd

Tags: c++, casting, eigen

How do you convert  an `ArrayXXd`  array to a `MatrixXd`?
So far I've done

```
MatrixXd temp_mat = my_array;
```

and the implicit conversion seems to work fine, but is this the way it is supposed to be done? Or is there some explicit conversion operation I should be doing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, implicit conversion is intended to work as you are doing it.

If you want to "view" an `Array` as a `Matrix` without actually copying it, you can use the [`.matrix()`](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1ArrayBase.html#af01e9ea8087e390af8af453bbe4c276c) method. E.g.,

```
ArrayXXd A;
VectorXd v;

VectorXd r = A.matrix() * v; // matrix vector product
```

There is an inverse to this method called [`.array()`](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1MatrixBase.html#a354c33eec32ceb4193d002f4d41c0497).

This is described in more detail in the "Converting between array and matrix expressions" section of [the tutorial on the `Array` class](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__TutorialArrayClass.html).